# how to make the vim plugin "Project" and "Mini Buffer Explorer" work together?

Tags: plugins, vim

As the title says, I need to make these plugins work together well. The mini buffer explorer just automatically opens after I open the second file(press Enter in project plugin window), then Mini Buffer Explorer opens as the third window on the top of my screen.
But after I switch back to project plugin window and press Enter to open the third file, a fourth window opened! It seems project plugin can't overwrite the second file's window.

Project plugin 1.4.1
Mini Buffer Explorer plugin 6.4.0